# Python-Django: ifchanged template tag

Tags: python, django

Here i am getting employee with duration from database.Same employee with 2 or 3 records.
so gettting employee duration and adding and displaying,if employee ID changed then
again it calculate the employee duration and displaying
I need fo find each employee ID has how many records,through `{{ forloop.counter }}`individually

Here my problems are...

1. If my loop coming to `{% ifchanged eachSc.laEmpNum %}` then `{{ result.0 }}`. If again then `{{ result.1 }}` and `{{ result.2 }}` then so on...
2. If my loop coming to `{% ifchanged eachSc.laEmpNum %}` then my `{{ forloop.counter }}` should start with 0(zero) again.

`result = [5.5, 4.5, 1.3]` which i am getting from `view.py`

```
{% for eachSc in DBShots1 %}

<tr>
    {% ifchanged eachSc.laEmpNum %} 

    <td bgcolor="#FFFACD" width="1%">Tot={{ result }}</td>
    {% endifchanged %}

</tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFACD" width="1%">{{ forloop.counter }} </td> 

    <td bgcolor="#CCFACD" width="1%">{{ eachSc.sName }}</td>

    <td bgcolor="#CCF0F5" width="1%">{{ eachSc.duration }}</td>

    <td bgcolor="#CCFACD" width="1%">{{ eachSc.frames }}</td>

    <td bgcolor="#CCFACD" width="5%">{{ GetEmpDept }} - {{ getEmpName.emp_name }} - {{ eachSc.laEmpNum }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I didn't catch the question, but maybe you are looking for variable `{{ forloop.counter0 }}`?. It starts from 0

Comment: If I understand correctly your problem, the template tag regroup (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup) might be of a help to you

Comment: If suppose i have 5 scenes then my present code {{ forloop.counter }} is giving 
1,2,3,4,5 as serial number

1. SC_SH_01   
2. SC_SH_02
3. SC_SH_03 and so on....

{% ifchanged eachSc.laEmpNum %} 
    <td bgcolor="#FFFACD" width="1%">Tot={{ result }}</td>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFACD" width="1%">{{ forloop.counter }} </td> 
{% endifchanged %}

If my "eachSc.laEmpNum" changed firsttime {% ifchanged eachSc.laEmpNum %} then my
{{ forloop.counter }} should start with 1,2. If again my "eachSc.laEmpNum" changed
then my { forloop.counter }} should start with 1,2,3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there are a couple of issues to deal with here. First of all I see you want to print an item of the 'result' variable, depending on the position of the forloop counter. This is not directly possible in django templates (for various fair reasons). To  quickly solve this without reorganizing your data in the view, you can define a custom filter that simply returns a list item on the specified index. You could put this in your templatetags/myfilters.py:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def getitem(mylist, index):
    return mylist[index]
```

Then, to reset the forloop counter when 'laEmpNum'  changes you should use the 'regroup' django template tag like this:

```
{% load myfilters %}
{% regroup DBShots1 by laEmpNum as eachScList %}
{% for eachScGrp in eachScList %}
    {% for eachSc in eachScGrp.list %}
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFACD" width="1%">{{ forloop.counter }} </td> 
      <td bgcolor="#CCFACD" width="1%">{{ eachSc.sName }}</td>
      <td bgcolor="#CCF0F5" width="1%">{{ eachSc.duration }}</td>
      <td bgcolor="#CCFACD" width="1%">{{ eachSc.frames }}</td>
      <td bgcolor="#CCFACD" width="5%">{{ GetEmpDept }} - {{ getEmpName.emp_name }} - {{ eachSc.laEmpNum }}</td>
     </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    <tr>
        <td> </td><td> </td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFACD" width="1%">Tot={{ result|getitem:forloop.counter0 }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The first line loads our custom filter library. The last part uses the custom filter to retrieve a result item based on the iteration over the 'laEmpNum' groupper.