# Using ifchanged

Tags: python, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python-Django: ifchanged template tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430520/python-django-ifchanged-template-tag)

This is my present code:

```
{% for eachSc in DBShots1 %}
 <tr>
    {% ifchanged eachSc.laEmpNum %} 

      <td> </td><td> </td>                                  
      <td bgcolor="#FFFACD" width="1%">Tot={{ result }}</td>

    {% endifchanged %}

 </tr>
  <td bgcolor="#FFFACD" width="1%">{{ forloop.counter }} </td> 

  <td bgcolor="#CCFACD" width="1%">{{ eachSc.sName }}</td>

   <td bgcolor="#CCF0F5" width="1%">{{ eachSc.duration }}</td>

  <td bgcolor="#CCFACD" width="1%">{{ eachSc.frames }}</td>

  <td bgcolor="#CCFACD" width="5%">{{ GetEmpDept }} - {{ eachSc.laEmpNum }}</td>

{% endfor %}
```

From the above code it displays like below:

```
 Tot=[(u'1046', 5.5), (u'8008', 4.5), (u'8011', 1.3)]
```

1-------01------2.5-------------60------allLayout - 1046

2-------02------2.0-------------48------allLayout - 1046

3-------04------1.0--------------0------allLayout - 1046

```
 Tot=[(u'1046', 5.5), (u'8008', 4.5), (u'8011', 1.3)]
```

4-------03------2.3-------------50------allLayout - 8008

5-------06------2.2-------------0-------allLayout - 8008

```
 Tot=[(u'1046', 5.5), (u'8008', 4.5), (u'8011', 1.3)]
```

6-------05------1.3-------------0-------allLayout - 8011

But my output should be display like below:
if empID change(1046,8008,8011) then
{{ forloop.counter }} should start with one(1) and {{ result }} should display first element((1046,5.5) for first ID(1046)
second(8008',4.5) element for second ID(8008) and so on:

1-------01------2.5-------------60------allLayout - 1046

2-------02------2.0-------------48------allLayout - 1046

3-------04------1.0-------------0-------allLayout - 1046

```
     Tot=(1046,5.5)
```

1-------03------2.3-------------50------allLayout - 8008

2-------06------2.2-------------0-------allLayout - 8008

```
    Tot=(8008', 4.5)
```

1-------05------1.3-------------0-------allLayout - 8011

```
    Tot=(8011', 1.3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use ifchanged here.

You should index your `result` with `forloop.counter0` but is not possible with django templating system.

You can write a custom tag to do this or change your view adding your result to the object context.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problem :

1. Show Tot only specific empID not all from string :

   **Ans** : You cannot do this because you can't use variables for attribute names, dictionary keys or list indizes that make you cannot show only specific index in array from  your counter. You may need to put this value to your list DBShots1 before show it on template or create a custom template tags.
2. Reset counter every time it change empID :

   **Ans** : You can use regroup function to sort your list that will make another for loop for each empID 
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#regroup

e.g.

```
{% regroup DBShots1 by eachSc.laEmpNum as emp_list %}
{% for eachSc in emp_list %}
        <tr>
            <td> </td><td> </td> 
            <td bgcolor="#FFFACD" width="1%">EmpNum : {{ eachSc.grouper }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% for item in eachSc.list %}
            <td bgcolor="#FFFACD" width="1%">{{ forloop.counter }} </td> 
            <td bgcolor="#CCFACD" width="1%">{{ item.sName }} </td>
            <td bgcolor="#CCF0F5" width="1%">{{ item.duration }}</td>
            <td bgcolor="#CCFACD" width="1%">{{ item.frames }}</td>
            <td bgcolor="#CCFACD" width="5%">{{ GetEmpDept }} - {{ item.laEmpNum }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```